# LM interpretation t value = 0 and Pr(>|t|) = 1

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I am working on a dataset with two variables for my **thesis**:

- sensor_value: numerical variable containing information about the value gathered by the sensor
- `cat_quality`: categorical variable of 4 levels measuring the reliability/quality of the information gathered by the sensor. It ranges from `0 (No signal)` to `3 (extremely reliable)`.

For supplying additional information about the proportion of the population, level 0 (0.003%); level 1 (11.93%); level 2(0.32%); level 3(87.74%).

I have reasons to think when `sensor_value` is equal to `0` can represents **both**:

- **absence** of the phenomena
- **missing** value

This is clear by observing the following boxplot

[image]

Observing the boxplot it becomes clear `sensor_value` is "influenced" by `cat_quality`because for level 0 and level 1 the value recorded by the sensor is equal 0. This 0 does not represent absence of phenomena but a missing value because the quality was extremely poor that the sensor was not able to gather data.

To further investigate **using an academic approach**, I run a a `multiple linear model` in R using as `predictor` **cat_quality** and as `dependent variable` **sensor_value**.

Here is the result:

```
Call:
lm(formula = sensor_value ~ cat_quality, data = temp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-37.844 -18.531  -2.438  10.437 250.230 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   8.016e-08  1.429e+00    0.00        1    
cat_quality1 -8.417e-08  1.429e+00    0.00        1    
cat_quality2  3.641e+01  1.435e+00   25.37   <2e-16 ***
cat_quality3  3.784e+01  1.429e+00   26.48   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 27.75 on 13812127 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1635,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1635 
F-statistic: 8.999e+05 on 3 and 13812127 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

### My question: HOW DO I INTERPRET/UNDERSTAND the meaning of t-value equal to 0 and Pr(>|t|) equal to 1?

#### Is it correct to conclude this variable should be dropped because 12% of values are not reliable/missing?

Comment: Study the concept of contrasts (in particular "treatment contrasts") and look up the definition of the t-value.

Comment: thank you! do you have any link to suggest about treatment contrasts?

Comment: Your approach is invalid for these data because the data are very strongly heteroscedastic.  What model to use, and how to interpret its results, depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps you could edit your post to provide some information about that.

Comment: What I need to accomplish is to find the best accademic and robust approach saying that this variable should be dropped because 12% of its values are equal to zero due to a strong association with another variable (`cat_quality`). Any suggestion about how to edit the question?